# ¿Cómo cerrar menú haciendo click fuera del mismo?

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas tardes, tengo un menú lateral que únicamente se cierra y se abre haciendo click en una de las opciones o haciendo click en al botón de "cerrar", el problema es que quiero que se cierre al hacer click fuera de este.
Este es "mi"(Esa parte el sitio web no fue hecha por mi) menú.

```
  <div id="options" class="sidenav">
     <a id="btnCloseMenu" href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
     <a href="#Inicio" onclick="closeNav()">Inicio</a>
     <a href="#acerca-de" onclick="closeNav()">Qu&eacute; hacemos</a>
     <a href="#servicios-size" onclick="closeNav()">Servicios</a>
     <a href="#proyectos-size" onclick="closeNav()">Sectores</a>
     <a href="#sectores-size" onclick="closeNav()">Proyectos</a>
     <a href="#contacto-link" onclick="closeNav()">Unete al equipo</a>
     <a href="#mensaje-link" onclick="closeNav()">Contacto</a>
  </div>
  <div id="fade"></div>
  <div class="top_header">
     <div class="bg transition"></div>
     <div class="menu-collapse">
        <div>
           <button id="btnMenu" type="button" class="btn" onclick="openNav()">
           <span class="line"></span>
           </button>
        </div>
     </div>
     <header class="">
        <div class="row">
           <a href="#Inicio">
           <img src="Images/PV_Manpower_bco.png"alt="PVmanpower logo">
           </a>
        </div>
     </header>
  </div>

//Esté es el scrip que se encarga de que abra o cierre
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("options").style.width = "280px";
    document.getElementById("btnMenu").style.visibility= "hidden";
    document.getElementById("btnCloseMenu").style.visibility= "visible";

}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("options").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("btnMenu").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("btnCloseMenu").style.visibility= "hidden";
}

function hideMenu() {
  document.getElementById("options").style.display = "none";
}
```

Cualquier observación externa el problema mencionado es perfectamente bienvenida, gracias.

Comment: quieres que al hacer click en cualquier parte de la página se abre o cierre el menu?

Comment: @Sr1871 Que se cierre al hacer click en cualquier parte de la página, lo siento si expliqué mal. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes utilizar la funcion closeNav() para cerrar el menu desde cualquier parte del codigo con jquery.

ejemplo

```
$("#botonQuieroCerrarMenuDesdeAfuera").click(
     function(event) {
      closeNav();

  }
);
```

Tambien te propongo que hagas una funcion que se llama toggle para que al hacer click, abre o cierre dependiendo del status del menu. De este modo reutilizas las funciones openNav() y closeNav().

```
 var nav = true;

 function toggleNav() {

 nav ? closeNav() : openNav();

}
```